# Does expander break OxyPlot?

Tags: wpf-controls, oxyplot

When my application starts up I don't want a visible Chart as there's nothing that's been processed. I thought I can "hide" the Chart in an Expander - (simple minded, perhaps). The following code appears to break OxyPlot:

```xml
<StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="4" Orientation="Horizontal">
   <Expander ExpandDirection="Right">
      <oxy:Plot Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="4" Title="Plot"
         x:Name="ChartPlot" Title="Ein Grafik" 
         Model="{Binding PlotModel}">
      </oxy:Plot>
   </Expander>
</StackPanel>
```

What *don't* I understand about either the Expander or the OxyPlot control?
Or perhaps there are "better practices" to hide Content until it's ready?

Answer (score 0):

Give your plot a size.  As is, it thinks it has 0 space. Or enclose it in a grid that has a size.